# javafx how to get return value from message box

Tags: javafx, return-value, messagebox

I have a problem I can not get a return value because i want use it in controller. How can I get a return value from checkbox after close the window. Because I need a return value in controller. Thanks

> ```
> import javafx.event.EventHandler;
> import javafx.geometry.Pos;
> import javafx.scene.Scene;
> import javafx.scene.control.Button;
> import javafx.scene.control.Label;
> import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
> import javafx.stage.Modality;
> import javafx.stage.Stage;
>
> public class CheckBox {
>
>   public static String display(String title, String message){
>       Stage window = new Stage();
>       String id = " ";
>
>       window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
>       window.setTitle(title);
>       window.setMinWidth(250);
>
>       Label label = new Label();
>       label.setText(message);
>
>       Button yButton = new Button("Y");
>       Button nbButton = new Button("N");
>       yButton.setId("Y");
>       nbButton.setId("N");
>       yButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
>       nbButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
>
>       VBox layout = new VBox(10);
>       layout.getChildren().addAll(label,yButton, nbButton);
>       layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
>       Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
>       window.setScene(scene);
>       window.showAndWait();
>
>       if(yButton.isPressed())
>           return yButton.getId();
>
>       else if(nbButton.isPressed())
>           return nbButton.getId();
>
>       return null;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get back from this dialogue?

Comment: if user click Ybutton, I would like to return Y, which is id and get a string "Y" in controller  @mrmcwolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would advise you not to use names that match those from standard libraries. The name `CheckBox` is inappropriate because it has control with that name. Use something descriptive, like `CheckBoxDialog`.

Refrain from using a static context. In this case, this is unnecessary and shows a bad style.

This is a sample implementation by keeping the static method you use.

```
public class CheckBoxDialog {
    public static final String YES = "Y";
    public static final String NO = "N";

    private String exitCode = NO;

    private Stage window;
    private Label label;

    public CheckBoxDialog() {
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setMinWidth(250);

        label = new Label();

        Button yButton = new Button(YES);
        Button nbButton = new Button(NO);

        yButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            exitCode = YES;
            window.close();
        });

        nbButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            exitCode = NO;
            window.close();
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label,yButton, nbButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        window.setTitle(title);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        label.setText(message);
    }

    public String showAndWait() {
        window.showAndWait();
        return exitCode;
    }

    public static String display(String title, String message){
        CheckBoxDialog dlg = new CheckBoxDialog();
        dlg.setTitle(title);
        dlg.setMessage(message);

        return dlg.showAndWait();
    }
}
```